# Auto Populate VPN Connection (Python / Bash)

Tags: python, bash

I want to create a Python script that connects to a vpn and auto populates the username and password then makes the connection. It's an openvpn connection that prompts firstly for the username followed by the password.

The username and password can be stored in the script itself of in a seperate .txt. I know this is bad practice but this is a personal thing (not corporate) and also only a temporary thing so the security risk is minimal

This is what I have so far -

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hey" $user
cd /home/vpn/
openvpn nameofvpnfile.ovpn

$SHELL
```

at that point when ran the connection is made and im promted for a username and then creds.

Comment: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/kb/articles/how-can-i-make-openvpn-remember-my-username-and-password

Comment: Hi sorry, this does not answer my question as its based on Windows and Mac OS, I need this for a Linux system.

Comment: The `auth-user-pass` option works on Linux too.